# How to visualize isometric map in Mapbox, Openstreetmap

Tags: visualization, mapbox, openstreetmap

I saw very nice map visualization by the city of Melbourne here:
http://www.pedestrian.melbourne.vic.gov.au/#date=11-03-2018&sensor=Col270_T&time=10
[image]

The map on this page is using Mapbox and OpenStreetMap (based on the credit in the bottom right corner). But I would like to know how did they accomplish tilting the map into Isometric.

I tried looking for a solution, but could not find the working one.

e.g. There is a link to this: http://osm.kyblsoft.cz/3dmapa/info. But its Github seems to disappeared.

Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Set pitch and bearing](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/set-perspective/) in the Mapbox GL JS documentation.

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v9',
    center: [-73.5804, 45.534830],
    pitch: 60, // pitch in degrees
    bearing: -60, // bearing in degrees
    zoom: 10
});
```